# Automatically detecting clusters in a 2d array/heatmap

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have run object detection on a video file and summed the seconds each pixel is activated to find the amount of time an object is shown in this area which gives me a 2d array of time values. Since these objects are in the same position of the video most of the time it leads to some areas of the screen having much higher activation than others. Now I would like to find a way to automatically detect "clusters" without knowing the number of clusters beforehand. I have considered using something like k-means but also read a little about finding local maximums, but I can't quite figure out how to put all this together or which method is the best to go with. Also, the objects vary in size, so I'm not sure I can go with the local maximum method?

The final result would be a list of ids and maximum time value for each cluster.

```
[[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
 [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]]
```

From this example array I would end out with a list:

```
id | Seconds
1  |  3
2  |  2
```

I havn't tried much since I have no clue where to start and any recommendations of methods with code examples or links to where I can find it to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: there are **a lot** of ways of approaching this with advantages depending on details you haven't included.  I'd suggest reading about [mixture modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) rather than clustering as your problem sounds closer to the former.  start with 1d mixtures, and then move on to 2d after that

Comment: @SamMason thanks a lot I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at different methods for clustering in: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

If you do not know the number of clusters beforehand you might want to use a different algorithm than K-means (one which is not dependent on the number of clusters). I would suggest reading about dbscan and hdbscan for this task. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply :) I actually ended up using dbscan before your comment and it works really well for this task, so I accepted your answer. I still need to do some testing on how well it generalizes with the same parameter settings for different results. I just randomly adjusted them until I had acceptable results without really knowing what they do. I'll update the question with my results so far.